# no resource found on android studio

Tags: android-studio

i have a little problem

for my activities, i created 2 differents styles, i had no problem with it but suddenly it couldn't build anymore,

i had 4 errors

---

"No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'"

"No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textSize'"

"No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'"

"No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textSize'"

---

on the /app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml.

and i have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The message you have shared seems there is a problem in the debug.

So you can simply perform ***CLEAN_PROJECT*** from the ***BUILD OPTION*** and then ***REBUILD_PROJECT***.

If that still fails, try ***restarting*** the Android Studio.

Comment: i tried, but it still won't works 

thanks anyway

Comment: Can you share the related codes for  layout and values ?

Comment: You can also check if the textColor and textSize are valid in your styles.

Comment: ok finally, i just rewrited each broken line, and it's finally working

thanks your answer, you gave me the idea !

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can accept the answer if you feel it has helped and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is what i added in the styles :

---

```
<style name="title">

    <item name="android:layout_margin">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

</style>

<style name="text">

    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:textStyle"></item> -->

</style>
```

---

which has been added into the values file, in the intermediates res.

and the error is precisely in this file.